# retrieve data using ajax and send alert

Tags: php, ajax

I've just started fiddling around with ajax and am trying to create a simple method to retrieve data from a php page and display a message upon successful retrieval but it doesnt seem to be working.

Here is my html page with the ajax code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>



    </body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'test2.php',
                success: function(data) {
                  if(data == "hello") 
                    alert('Data Received');
                }
              });
              });
        </script>
</html>
```

and here is the php page

```
<?php
echo 'hello';
?>
```

Comment: If you remove `if(data == "hello") ` does it work ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
        $.ajax({
        url : 'test2.php',
        dataType : 'html',
        success : function (result) {
            alert(result);
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
```

should work. For this echo, "text" as dataType is fine.

Comment: Why would work? why use `POST` ? (I didn't downvote you)

Comment: you are right, just took this from a method I used. Post should not be neccessary, only if you submit data to php. going to edit

Comment: Thank you this works! but assuming my test2.php file has certain processes to complete first before echoing out data, is there any way to set it to wait until data is echoed before alerting it?

Comment: this depends on your php. Just echo the data after completing the "tasks".

Comment: Maybe i can a bit clearer. Right now in my html page, i have a file upload form, that will submit a file to test2.php. At test2.php, i have certain validation checks that will echo out "success" upon successful validation and "Failed" when failed. I want to set it the ajax function to activate only after I've upload the file and the checks are done. Right now the ajax is activated before i even submit the form so it displays nothing in the alert box since nothing has been echoed out yet by test2.php.